# Cin input of multiple lines not iterating correctly

Tags: c++, string, input, cin

I came from C so I'm trying to understand C++ input.

I want to read lines of input like so:

```
3
0 0 1 0
1 4 0 1
0 1 2 3
```

where 3 is the number of input lines I'm going to read next. My code is

```
  #include<iostream>
  #include<string>
   
  int main() {
    int n, k = 8;
    std::cin >> n;
    
   char lines[n][k];
   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
     std::cin.getline(lines[i], k);
 }
```

I should be able to read the `n` lines (because of the zeroth iteration) but it only goes for `n-1`, so it finishes the reading at `n-2`. I don't understand why and how to deal with it and properly read input like this.

Also: how would I do if I wanted to read the same way for a `std::string`? Would I use `std::string *lines[n];`?

Comment: Where does the 6 come from? E.g. in ```char lines[n][6]```?

Comment: `int n; ... char lines[n][6];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their sizes denoted by a compile-time value, not a runtime value.  Dynamic arrays in C++ are done by using `std::vector`.

Comment: As @PaulMcKenzie said, I was about to propose a solution with ```std::vector```, but I'm not sure I understand your approach to be honest.

Comment: I believe you should just start over and use `std::vector`.  What you posted is not valid C++, even with your `std::string` example.

Comment: @JakubCieślak I have corrected it. The k = 8 is the expected length of the string (when I copied I simplified that bit of the code and forgot to change that)

Comment: I wonder when the da*n extensions that allows `T arr[nonconst]` to work will be nuked :D

Comment: @beatle the length of the string is 7 according to what I see... anyway, this isn't legal in standard C++, you should check the answer below.

Comment: @Enlico -- *I wonder when the da*n extensions that allows T arr[nonconst] to work will be nuked* -- I also wished that gcc and clang would turn off the extensions by default, and only allow them using a compiler switch.  What is happening now is that new programmers use the non-standard syntax thinking that they are writing valid C++ code.  Then they write a mountain of code using this syntax, and then get disappointed when told that the code they wrote isn't valid.

Comment: You should avoid formatted input ```cin >> foo``` mixed with unformatted input ```cin.getline(foo, bar)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to create variadic length arrays, they are not a part of standard C++.

You should be using a combination of [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> //std::string, std::getline
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cin.ignore();

    std::vector<std::string> lines(n);

    for (auto& line : lines) {
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
    }
}
```

The `std::ignore` is needed because when using `std::cin` an additional `\n` is added after pressing enter. The next `std::getline` will be aborted when seeing the `\n`. So the `ignore` removes the next additional character from `std::cin`. read more on [why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction)

Comment: Why does one need the line: ``std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());``

Comment: It still only allows ``n-1`` inputs

Comment: @beatle I edited, does it still only accept `n - 1` inputs?